# What is the meaning of "spend it living" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Sam: My mom left when I was little. My dad raised me and he died last
>   year.
>
> Cathy: Oh, my. So you cared for him as well?
>
> Sam: I would have. I just thought I had more time.
>
> Cathy: You think too much about the time you have left. you don't
>   **spend it living.**

I don't get it, what Cathy is speaking here about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll rephrase Cathy's line:

> You think too much about the time you have left. You don't spend **that time living life to the fullest**.

Cathy is saying not to brood too much about how short life is. Instead, live your life as though the time is precious. Don't just think -- live. *Carpe diem*.

Answer (score 0):

We can spend time {**doing** something}.  The participial phrase complement describes how the time is spent

> She spent time *thinking*.
>
> He spent ten minutes *drinking* a cup of coffee before he sat down to
>   work.
>
> He has spent the last six months *pining* for his ex-girlfriend.
>
> You can spend your days *living* in the moment, or *worrying* about
>   the future, or *regretting* past mistakes.